# JS - Can't combine lib files

Tags: javascript, html, shared-libraries, synchronous

I have multiple lib files in an an index.html file, that are loaded in proper sequence for an app I am running.

```
<!-- example of some of them... -->
<script src="/./sys/lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/./sys/lib/jquery.ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="/./sys/lib/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<script src="/./sys/lib/underscore.min.js"></script>
<script src="/./sys/lib/handlebars.min.js"></script>
<script src="/./sys/lib/backbone.min.js"></script>
<script src="/./sys/lib/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="/./sys/lib/libs.extensions.js"></script>
```

These run fine, they are already all minified.

Now, I want to combine these all into one file for load speed:

```
<script src="/./sys/lib/libs.all.js"></script>
```

So I open up the new `libs.all.js` file, and one by one paste the minified .js files into it, with *zero* modification, in the *exact same sequence* as listed above. This works until I get to moment.js. When I then paste that in and run it, I get a JS error.

```
TypeError: (intermediate value)(...) is not a function
```

I don't get what I am missing - if I paste them in the right sequence as they synch loaded in the HTML file, what is the difference?

Comment: Most probably one of your js files is missing a ; at the end. Open up the one you believe is causing the error and add a ; at the end, or add a ; to the very first line of the next js file.

Comment: Can you turn your comment into an answer? You totally nailed it and I need to accept your answer.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Most probably one of your js files is missing a `;` at the end. Open up the one you believe is causing the error and add a `;` at the end, or add a `;` to the very first line of the next js file.

Comment: omg thank you so much. you have no idea how much i struggled in this

Comment: Thank you, this saved me a ton of time :)

Comment: Thanks, helped me alot!

Answer (score 2):

Modifying the javascript code is not fixing the root cause of the problem so this could happen again as soon as you introduce a new JavaScript file.

You have at least few choices for a permanent fix - they involve changing the build so that this cannot happen in the future, even if a semi-colon is missing:

- Inject a `;` between the files you are concatenating. This is usually a simple one-line change depending on how you are concatenating the files.
- Minify the files first and then concatenate. This should leave a \n between the files you are concatenating, allowing ASI to take care of this for you.

Answer (score 2):

just add semi-clone and newline

```
';\n'
```

at end of each file