# What causes (intermediate value)(...) is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to merge my JS files.

Anyway, I get an error like that: `TypeError: (intermediate value)(...) is not a function` at `})(jQuery);`. The code is the following:

```
(function($) {

    //function body and stuff

})(jQuery);
```

So, I put the code in JSLint, to check for syntax errors, brakes closure... everything is correct.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**

the file tha is being put before the file where I get the error (when merged): http://jsfiddle.net/ENDhB/1/

the file where I get the error: http://jsfiddle.net/ZTP6r/

I tried putting `;` before the `(function($) {`, but then I get `TypeError: $(...).makeacolumnlists is not a function` in the 1st merged file.

Comment: Any online link where this issue can be checked?

Comment: do you actually have code in the function body? maybe something there is causing the issue but its reporting it at a diff location

Comment: can you please provide fiddler for that

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20307462/js-cant-combine-lib-files that might be your issue

Comment: @gillesc Seems relevant, then OP should try: `;(function($) {...})(jQuery);`

Comment: I updated my question with JSFiddle examples and some things that I've tried.

Comment: side-note: jsFiddle was down all morning but seems to be on/off at the moment: [**https://twitter.com/jsfiddle**](https://twitter.com/jsfiddle) might use jsBin or other service in the meantime

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue with none of the two jsfiddles. Please create a single jsfiddle that reproduces your issue and tell us what browser you get the issue in. Also, please try to remove as much code as possible such that the issue still appears.

Comment: (As a first bet, I remember I had issues with your syntax in the past and moved the closing parenthesis: `(function($) { ... } (jQuery));`