# TypeError: (intermediate value)(intermediate value).success is not a function (angular)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller, angularjs-http

I have difficulties understanding this error... I dont quite understand why its not a function....

```
angular.module('mkApp').factory('mkService', function ($http, $log) {
  function getLookUp(successcb) {
    $http = ({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'api/Entries/'

    }).success(function (data, status, header, config) {
        successcb(data);
    }).
    error(function (data, status, header, config) {
        $log, warn(data, status, header, config);
    });
  };

  return {
    lookUp: getLookUp
  }
});

angular.module('mkApp').controller('mkControler', function ($scope, mkService) {
  mkService.lookUp(function (data) {
    $scope.ddl = data;
    console.log(ddl);

  });
});
```

And here is my HTML

```
<div ng-app="mkApp">
    <div ng-controller="mkControler">            
       <table>
           <tr>
               <td> First Name</td>
               <td> Last Name</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td><input type="text" /></td>
               <td><input type="text" /></td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>
                   <select></select>
               </td>
           </tr>
       </table>

    </div>
</div>
```

My idea is to use data to populate drop down. It does bring me XML back. 
Any help please i've been looking everywhere now.
Thank you.

Comment: It is difficult to understand what you are asking. Maybe you could reword your question to make it clearer?

Comment: JavaScript was giving me error... It happen to be that I used incorrect syntax.

Comment: This is what helped me, if you are minifying: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20307462/js-cant-combine-lib-files

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `$http` call code should be `$http({` instead of `$http = ({` and also `$log, warn` should be `$log.warn`

**Code**

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'api/Entries/'
}).success(function (data, status, header, config) {
    successcb(data);
}).
error(function (data, status, header, config) {
    $log.warn(data, status, header, config);
});
```

Comment: Also, I was reading a little and it seems that its better to use recourse instead of HTTP. I wont have to call those success functions. Will my controller be different if ill use resource instead of http?

Comment: No..thats not correct..the imllementation you are talking is also possilble in $http..$resource is also good while dealing with REST API..

Comment: I cant, don't have permission yet :(